# SCSS not working in a jsfiddle - related to cross browser bug

Tags: html, css

I need help on a positioning issue - I have a span underneath an img in an li tag. I have the example but none of the styles are rendering? The link is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/ymm8xpb8/16/

The problem I'm trying to solve (outside of the jsfiddle) is that in firefox, the span tags are overlaying the image on the top, but in Chrome and Safari, they are directly under the image. The markup from jsfiddle is below:

```
<ul class="title-preview">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="">
        <span>Some tile text below the image</span>
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="">
        <span>Some tile text below the image</span>
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="">
        <span>Some tile text below the image</span>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
.title-preview {
  list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    a {
        position: relative;
      }
    img {
         padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
      span {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: ralewayBold, sans-serif;
          width: 100px;
          color: $sn-primary-link;
      }
  }
}
```

1. Howcome the jsfiddle isn't applying the styles?
2. How can I consistently position the `<span>` tag underneath the image across browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a SCSS variable but not initializing it:

```
$sn-primary-link: red;

.title-preview {
  list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    a {
        position: relative;
      }
    img {
         padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
      span {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: ralewayBold, sans-serif;
          width: 100px;
          color: $sn-primary-link;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Agh! Thank you! Totally missed that.